# MySql Database Design- most efficient for columns that might be null?

Tags: mysql, database-design

In this database sometimes the employees are in just one jurisdiction, sometimes more than one. For instance, Bob's jurisidictions would be North America, South America, and Africa. While Janes would be just North America. However, each employee will always have a department.

Since some empoyees will only have one jurisidiction assigned to them while others may have more, is this the best way to implement jurisdictions? Or is there a more efficient way?

I will be using join statements and selecting by department for my queries.

```
employees
-----------------
userID (primary key)
deptID (foreign key and NOT NULL references departments)
firstName
lastName
jurisdiction1 (foreign key references jurisdictions)
jurisdiction2 (foreign key references jurisdictions)
jurisdiction3 (foreign key references jurisdictions)
jurisdiction4 (foreign key references jurisdictions)
jurisdiction5 (foreign key references jurisdictions)
jurisdiction6 (foreign key references jurisdictions)
jurisdiction7 (foreign key references jurisdictions)

jurisdictions
-------------------
jurID primary key
jurisdictionName


departments
--------------------
deptID primary key
departmentName
```

Comment: because using a employee-jurisdiction mapping table would be...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is better to have a new table `jurisdictions`, and `EmployeesJurisdictions`:

**`Jurisdictions`:**

- `Id`,
- `JurisdictionName`.

**`UsersJurisdictions`:**

- `EmployeeId` Foreign key references `Employees(EmployeeId)`.
- `JurisdictionId` a foreign key references `jurisdictions(jurisdictionId)`.

Comment: Should the UsersJurisdictions table have a primary key? Also, the UsersJurisdictions table foreign key "employeeID" is not updating and showing the user I inserted in employees table. I made sure I am using innodb engine.

Comment: Actually, is there a way to make the UserJurisdictions table foreign key EmployeeID populate automatically when I insert a record into empolyees table?

Comment: @dhee - For the table `UsersJurisdictions` you have to choices. Either create a composite key `(EmplooyeeId, JurisdictionId)`, or create a new key, a surrogate key, a primary key `Id`. If you want to populate the `EmployeeId` automatically when you insert a record in the employees table, one way is to use Triggers create an after insert trigger on the empoloyees table, this triggers will fire automatically when any record is inserted in the employees table, in this trigger make you insertion into the other table.

Comment: I've been doing alot of research on primary composite keys. If I made a `primary key(EmplooyeeId, JurisdictionId)` in table `UsersJurisdictions`, I would still use the same search such `"SELECT * FROM employees inner join jurisdictions ON employees.userID = jurisdictions.employeeID"`? What would be the benefit of the composite primary key rather than just 2 foreign keys without the composite primary key?

Comment: @dhee - The composite key will ensure that the combination of the `EmployeeID` and `JurisdictionId` is unique. So each `JurisdictionId` is unique for each `EmployeeId`, and there is no difference when joining the two tables, it will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The jurisdiction table design is not correct in your scheme. You need a intermediate table to store the relationship between user and region. Like this.

```
employee table
--------------
user_id
first_name
depart_id
j_id

jurisdiction table
-----------------
j_id
region

employee_jurisdiction
------------------
id
user_id 
j_id
(Set INDEX as no duplicate for user_id+j_id)
```

Comment: Why do you prefer not to use a foreign key? What would you use instead?

Comment: @dhee, please forget my last claim in answer which makes things complicated. Foreign key is necessary, it's okay to set it directly in database scheme.